# Eclipse prints stack trace but doesn't show variables. Bug?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, exception

In my application formerly I got an NPE and, by setting a breakpoint at NullPointerException, could get a break, stack trace (in the Debug window), and current variables in the Variables window.

However, now there is an uncaught ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException somewhere else. In Eclipse, when having set a breakpoint at that exception, I only get a stack trace *in console*, but no variables are seen in the Variables window. Is this a bug? I have also made sure the application does not catch the exception or prints the trace.

The breakpoint is so configured (copied):
ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: caught and uncaught (both switches ON)
Suspend thread is ON, all other switches are OFF.

First line of trace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
```

Comment: If it's only getting a stack trace in the console, that suggests you're not actually breaking into the code. Does the debugger actually pause at all?

Comment: Then I'm not surprised it's not showing variables - that's only going to happen when it actually triggers the break point. It suggests you haven't configured the break point properly, basically. Can you show a screenshot of where you think you've configured it?

Comment: And show a stack trace of the exception you are getting as well?

Comment: @JonSkeet That's a valid answer if this is a valid question.

Comment: @Keyser: Yeah, but without any real evidence about how the break point is set, I'm reluctant to just post an answer which is basically "You're doing it wrong."

Comment: The stack trace is really irrelevant. I could set a BP before the exception to solve it. The question is why does the BP exception not work? I have given details on how the BP is set.

Comment: I'm asking for the stack trace to verify you got the exception name right. There are similarly named exceptions, so it's an easy mistake.

Comment: I have copied the relevant part

Comment: Thanks, try a couple of things: Setting a breakpoint in the exception source code itself (at all of the possible constructors). And failing that, try setting a breakpoint in the superclass (making sure you tick the 'subclasses of this exception').

Answer (score 2):

The solution to my own question is: No this is not a bug. I started the application in the Eclipse Debug look via the small Play button on top of the Debug window. But this didn't start a debug session because I had started a Run session earlier. There was, however, not a visible indication of that in the whole frame. I would consider it a design bug personally.